Why the LateX instruction \Large doesn't run when used in Matplotlib label?
In the small program below, I don't understand why label = r"$\tilde{Q}$") runs well and label = r"$\Large{Q}$") doesn't run:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-3, +3, 100)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 2))
ax.plot(x, y,  label = r"$\tilde{Q}$")
#ax.plot(x, y,  label = r"$\Large{Q}$")
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()

The error generated by label = r"$\Large{Q}$" is incredibly verbose and I couldn't find a simple explanation.
Any suggestion appreciated as to apply \Large to a single letter in a label.

Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/how-to-use-large-and-its-variants

Thanks for the link. I expected to understand the answer in your link, but it's unclear as regards the problem. For example, label = r"$ \sigma  $" is good, but label = r"$ \begin{Large} \sigma \end{Large} $" is not. Could you be a bit more explicit?

I'm not sure if it's possible, but why not use the normal command and then change the legend fontsize?

Well, because I simplified the code. Actually, the label to write was  label = r"$Q(y|x)$") (dealing with some Metropolis-Hastings  stuff...) What I expected was to find a "pythonic" simple way to make just the first letter Q bigger (to be more accurately visualized on plot).

@Andrew: Try with r"$\mbox{\Large $Q$}$"; not sure whether it's necessary to escape to LaTeX via $ before using a command like \mbox.
